# Update Apk from Genexus 16U11 to 17U10, server url incorrect

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have an Android app developed with Genexus 16U11. In the past I have always released new versions (not on the marketplace) using the Genexus automatic update function (android version and server url)

[image]

The apps, upon connecting, detected the new version and automatically downloaded it

However, I converted the project to the 17U10 version of Genexus and now when I deploy the apps are unable to update. The user is directed to the server url choice page as the app is unable to connect with it, the error message says "The server url is incorrect"

But the service is running correctly, if I delete the app and directly download the new version, it works; it's just the automatic download from the old to the new version that seems faulty, as if the old version didn't recognize the new version published as a service.

I set the same Android Package Name for both APKs, but it still doesn't seem to work. What could be missing?

[image]

I see that in this version there is the possibility to select a panel for configuring the URL, but there is no documentation or example on how to write this panel (I tried to insert an empty panel in that field, but still the button does not appear)

What has changed?

Answer (score 0):

You currently have the setting "Dynamic Services URL=True." This indicates that end-users can select the service URL at runtime. However, based on my understanding, this is not the intended behavior for your application.

Your application seem to be designed to run with a specific URL, which the end-user should not be able to change. Therefore, I recommend changing the setting to "Dynamic Services URL=False," and the application will access the services using the predefined "Services URL" value.

For more detailed information, please refer to the following links:

[How to Change the URL Services of a Native Mobile Application](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?16159,HowTo%3A%20Change%20the%20URL%20Services%20of%20a%20Native%20Mobile%20application)

[Dynamic Services URL property](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20366,Dynamic%20Services%20URL%20property%22)

Comment: In fact, for this application that data is not essential to me, but in any case I don't understand why it is not selectable. In past versions, by setting the dynamic url I could choose it, I had the three dots at the top right. This is not the case here

Comment: You should use SetApplicationServerURL method.
This way you have more power to establish the URL, for example, request it from the user based on a domain of URLs (eg. combobox). You can also implement that the URL depends on the device or user, etc. without strictly asking the user for the URL, etc
More info:
About the change: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=49932;;
About how to set the URL:
  https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31310,Network+external+object#SetApplicationServerURL